# Google Chart API breaks when I use Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I am using MVC 4 and the google chart API, when I enable authorization in my web.config the interactivity of my chart breaks.  (Renders fine, but when I click a link for more information throws up an error not knowing what "google" is.

Below is my vbhtml page;

```
@Code
   ViewData("Title") = "Home Page"
End Code
@Section Head
   @Scripts.Render({"https://www.google.com/jsapi"})
End Section
<h3>Welcome to XXXXXXX</h3>
<p>
   This will be a multi-system dashboard
</p>
<div id="vacancyRates"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart('vacancyRates'));

function drawChart(container) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetVacancyRates",
        success: function (result) {
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
            var options = { title: 'Community Vacancy Rates', tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }, width: 500, height: 500, is3D: true };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(container));
            chart.setAction({
                id: 'searchCommunity',
                text: 'View Community',
                action: function () {
                    selection = chart.getSelection();
                    //open a search for that community
                    window.location.href = "/Units/?community=" + data.getFormattedValue(selection[0].row, 2);
                }
            });
            chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, msg) { alert(msg); }
    });
}
```

When I added the following entries into my web.config all heck broke loose.

```
<authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization>
```

*** I also added a couple other authorization tags to allow access to anonymous users to my CSS page and related scripts and images.

The strange thing is; the chart renders on load just fine, it is when the related action is triggered that the website crashes (in debug mode).  It fails on the line

```
google.load(....);
```

"google is undefined"

Thoughts?

---

**Things I have tried:**
Moving the script all to "@Section Head"
Changing the Render to "//www.google.com/jsapi"

---

**More things, I think I'm getting closer**
(keep in mind it only fails when authentication is on)
If I remove the "/?community=X" from the hyperlink it all works (although I dont get the results I want on the next page obviously)  In fact if I create another link on the page in the same format, with ?community the page fails outside of the google chart.

Comment: This is kind of outside my expertise (Google Charts API), but what I suspect is that jsapi isn't being loaded. I would load up your document in Chrome, inspect the page, and watch what JS errors are thrown in the console.

Comment: There are no errors thrown by the console in Chrome, in fact it works the first time.  Subsequently, I get logged out.  Weird, maybe its an issue with my forms authentication.  I don't know how that would effect an already rendered chart action.  Investigating....

Comment: It appears to be the fault of the window.location.href line in the javascript, perhaps this function partially reloads the current page?  I am currently investigating solutions to replace this call.